# Generate random cities based on probabilities

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables, one with country, city and the probability a user can be from that city, and another table with users and their countries:

| country | city | probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | New York | 0.3 |
| USA | Houston | 0.5 |
| USA | LA | 0.2 |

| user_id | country |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USA |
| 2 | USA |
| 3 | USA |
| 4 | USA |
| 5 | USA |
| 6 | USA |

In the second table, I want to create a new column (city) that randomly chooses a city from the table above based on the probability; so Houston should be chosen more often.

**Expected output (random)**:

| user_id | country | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | Houston |
| 2 | USA | Houston |
| 3 | USA | LA |
| 4 | USA | Houston |
| 5 | USA | New York |
| 6 | USA | New York |

I'm using pandas for this. Obviously there will be more countries and cities, and more users in different countries.

Comment: Obviously there will be some critics about this question. My gut tells me it sounds like an homework question.

Comment: It isn't. We got historical data with missing cities and I was told to generate random cities based on probabilities I calculated from the newer data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to generate a random sample according to a given probability distribution:

```py
In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame({"user_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "country": ["USA"]*6})

In [28]: df
Out[28]:
   user_id country
0        1     USA
1        2     USA
2        3     USA
3        4     USA
4        5     USA
5        6     USA

In [32]: df["city"] = np.random.choice(["New York", "Houston", "LA"], size=len(df), p=[0.3, 0.5, 0.2])

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
   user_id country      city
0        1     USA   Houston
1        2     USA   Houston
2        3     USA   Houston
3        4     USA        LA
4        5     USA   Houston
5        6     USA  New York
```

If users are in different countries you will need to do this once per country.

---

Edit: Solution which handles duplicates in the `user_id` column consistently:

```py
In [34]: df = pd.DataFrame({"user_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1], "country": ["USA"]*6})

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
   user_id country
0        1     USA
1        2     USA
2        3     USA
3        4     USA
4        4     USA
5        1     USA

In [36]: num_users = df["user_id"].nunique()

In [37]: num_users
Out[37]: 4

In [38]: cities = np.random.choice(["New York", "Houston", "LA"], size=num_users, p=[0.3, 0.5, 0.2])

In [39]: cities
Out[39]: array(['Houston', 'New York', 'LA', 'New York'], dtype='<U8')

In [40]: df["user_id"].unique()
Out[40]: array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)

In [41]: mapping = {user_id: city for user_id, city in zip(df["user_id"], cities)}

In [43]: df["city"] = df["user_id"].apply(mapping.get)

In [44]: df
Out[44]:
   user_id country      city
0        1     USA   Houston
1        2     USA  New York
2        3     USA        LA
3        4     USA  New York
4        4     USA  New York
5        1     USA   Houston
```

Comment: This works well, thank you. A small follow-up to this: sometimes I might get the same user_id in the second table. I only want one city per user_id. So if user_id 1 has 10 records, he needs to have one country and one city. How would that be done? I tried grouping by the user_id but it's not working.

Comment: Updated with an approach which gives the same city for every occurrence of a specific user_id.

Comment: I had to loop over the groupby of the user_id then a nester loop over the groupby of the country of that user, generate the random city, create a dataframe with unique user_ids and cities, and merge with the second dataset to capture all users with their countries and cities. But it worked thanks to your input.